# how to use real numbers as synthesis-able in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, digital

So I have an assignment where I have to build a Vending Machine using VHDL and also draw the ASM chart for it.
The vending machine provides 2 products and accepts 3 types of coins: 0.5nis, 1 nis and 2 nis(These coins are represented as signals C0, C1 and C2). When the user selects the product, he has to insert the price in coins. When the value of the money inserted equals or exceeds the listed price, the machine vends the item and returns the change also as signals (R0,R1 and R3 = 0.5,1 and 2 nis).
So I started building the ASM and defined a real variable called sum for summing the value of coins that are inserted but then I remembered that I would have a problem with the synthesizing because the real is not synthesis-able. 
I just want to ask, how to overcome the problem of the Real variable? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi9pa.jpg)

Comment: Use VHDL-2008. Depending on what you're using Real for, either the IEEE fixed point or floating point libraries will work. For money, floating point has obvious drawbacks, fixed point is a better match.

Comment: @BrianDrummond so instead of using real, should i use fixed points ? And if yes, can I add to the ASM chart a variable that has the type float ? So sorry if i sound stupid but i am not that good at VHDL

Comment: Don't make your life complicated. The smallest coin is 0.5. So multiply everything by 2 and the smallest value is 1, an integer again. Then you can just add integers, not floating point necessary. You just need to remember that the internal value is double that of the actual value. Using floating point would be overkill here.

Comment: Fixed point is one way of representing Real, Floating point is another.

Comment: @JHBonarius But what if he entered 3 * 0.5 coins and other integer coins ? Here it would still be a fraction.

Comment: No, 3*0.5*2=3. Don't just x2 one thing, x2 everything.... Other example five 0.5 coin + seven 1 coin + three 2 coins = 2*(5*0.5+7*1+3*2)=2*15.5=31.

Comment: @JHBonarius AAAH ! I got it ! Thank you  it's a really good idea